# How do I prevent repainting in Pinescript when I am using a tuple?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to implement this repainting function but I am getting an error message stating that "The `_src` parameter of the `f_security()` function cannot accept a tuple as an argument. Pass a single argument to this parameter."

I tried this and didn't get any errors, but it didn't solve my problem of the HTF data changing when the LTF close and I want the data to be from the previous candle until its closed on the HTF.

```
[GreenAnchor01, BlueAnchor01, RedAnchor01, OrangeAnchor01, fsr01_TF1, LeFV01_TF1, EMA01_TF1, price01, rsi01_TF1, repaint01] = request.security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, EMA, close, RSI, barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
```

Here is another option I tried:

```
[GreenAnchor01, BlueAnchor01, RedAnchor01, OrangeAnchor01, fsr01_TF1, LeFV01_TF1, EMA01_TF1, price01, rsi01_TF1] = request.security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, EMA, (close[indexHighTF])[indexCurrTF], RSI], gaps= barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

I have 12 assets I call to put data into a table so I can't call each one individually.

Does anyone know of a work around?

```
// Allow or Prevent Repainting Function
f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

[GreenAnchor01, BlueAnchor01, RedAnchor01, OrangeAnchor01, fsr01_TF1, LeFV01_TF1, EMA01_TF1, price01, rsi01_TF1, repaint] = f_security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, EMA, close, RSI], allowRepainting)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're thinking is correct.
Here's an example how to use a tuple with request security getting the last confirmed open/close values on eg. 5min from 1h with NO repainting.

```
[o, c] = request.security("", "60", [open[1], close[1]], gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(o, "1h open")
plot(c, "1h close")
```

You can easily  use a tuple just as you would use a simple variable. The important thing is to request "past" data with *lookahead_on* so that you only work with confirmed HTF values.
In addition, if you want the values to repaint, or repaint conditionally, just use a ternary operator at the indexed parameter AND use *barmerge.gaps_off*

```
repaint = input.bool(true, "Repaint")
[o, c] = request.security("", "60", [open[1], close[repaint ? 0 : 1]], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(o, "open") // will not repaint
plot(c, "close") // will repaint conditionally
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I tried [GreenAnchor01, BlueAnchor01, RedAnchor01, OrangeAnchor01, fsr01_TF1, LeFV01_TF1, EMA01_TF1, price01, rsi01_TF1] = request.security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, EMA, close, RSI], gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on, ignore_invalid_symbol=true)
and it is giving me NAN as the result for the close price.

Comment: My mistake. I mistyped the gap requirement. You'll have to use gaps_off in order to receive eg. close values continuously.